# datatable table tools not copy the filtered content

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable({
    "paging_scrolling": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": 'lfr<"outer"<"inner"t>>T<"clear">ip',
     "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
   }
  });
  oTable.fnSearchHighlighting();
```

This is my code for initialize the data table with scrolling,highlighting and table tool plugin are used. but when i search for particular content and save it as excel it saves total table data not the filtered data

Comment: What version are you using? Tabletools should really do that by itself, only hidden columns need special treatment.

Comment: I am using this version v1.9.4 I. Now i got solution for this issue.    Just add  "oSelectorOpts": {
                            "filter": "applied"
                      } . it can copy the filtered data alone

Comment: By using data-table-highlight plugin am highlighting the filtered data's. by using the function oTable.fnSearchHighlighting() in the above code.  But i Need to highlight the filter column grid heading too. is there any option to do that. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this version v1.9.4 I. Now i got solution for this issue. Just add

`"oSelectorOpts": { "filter": "applied" }` .

it can copy the filtered data alone